# Ler arquivo CSV ,Colunas

Tags: python, csv

Gostaria de saber como faço para ler um arquivo CSV pegando a primeira e segunda coluna e comparar a string contida nela com uma outra string que eu queira no código.

Ex.:

```
if(o conteudo do csv coluna 1=="positivo" && conteudo do csv coluna 2 =="negativo")
```

Comment: não !!Quero pegar a linha [0]coluna [1] e assim por diante

Comment: Você quer percorrer todas as linhas e todas as colunas do CSV ?

Comment: Conseguiu implementar minha resposta?

Comment: sim ,obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[TL;DR]](https://repl.it/Ji83)
 
Há várias maneiras de fazer isso, uma bem fácil seria a utilização do pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# Simulando um CSV
s = '''
Mesa,Entrada,Saida,Conta
01,16:00,18:00,95.00
02,14:00,18:00,195.00
03,18:00,21:00,75.00
04,16:30,18:30,75.00
05,16:00,18:45,178.00
'''

# Lendo o csv 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=['Mesa', 'Entrada', 'Saida', 'Conta'])

# Imprimindo o resultado
print(df)
       Mesa Entrada  Saida  Conta
0     1   16:00  18:00   95.0
1     2   14:00  18:00  195.0
2     3   18:00  21:00   75.0
3     4   16:30  18:30   75.0
4     5   16:00  18:45  178.0

# Imprimindo coluna específica
print(df['Entrada'])
0    16:00
1    14:00
2    18:00
3    16:30
4    16:00
Name: Entrada, dtype: object
```

Para iterar (navegar) nas linhas do dataframe:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row['Entrada'], row['Conta'])
```

**Saida:**

```
16:00 95.0
14:00 195.0
18:00 75.0
16:30 75.0
16:00 178.0
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it *](https://repl.it/Ji83)

* Tenha paciencia, no repl.it, o pandas parece que congela. :-)